# Camera work on emulator but not on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr

i'm having problem dealing with camera application on real device. when i run my application on genymotion emulator version 4.4.2(API 19) it works fine.. but when i run it on my real device Huawei P9 Lite version 6 (API 23) it crashes. Here is the errors that shows on the Logcat :

```
05-01 23:31:10.963 9308-9308/edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr W/CameraBase: An error 
occurred while connecting to camera: 0
05-01 23:31:10.963 9308-9308/edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr E/Camera-JNI: 
android_hardware_Camera_native_setup Error: -1 
05-01 23:31:10.963 9308-9308/edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr E/Camera: Camera new 
cameraInitNormal:-1
```

in my class where i handle the camera object i see that "android.hardware.camera is deprecated"
i think it maybe from this and i should use "android.hardware.camera2" instead. But as i use alot the camera object and it's methods it's going to be alot of change in my code. Can this be avoided ? or is this problem from an other thing ?

The permission for the camera is already included in my manifest and i'm using this configuration in my build file :

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 24
```

**UPDATE**

Here is why i think the problem is from deprecated methods :

```
try {

  // Open and initialize the camera
  cameraManager.openDriver(surfaceHolder);

  // Creating the handler starts the preview, which can also throw a RuntimeException.
  handler = new CaptureActivityHandler(this, cameraManager, isContinuousModeActive);

} catch (IOException ioe) {
  showErrorMessage("Error", "Couldn't initialize camera. Please try restarting device.");
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  // Barcode Scanner has seen crashes in the wild of this variety:
  // java.?lang.?RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
  showErrorMessage("Error", "Could not initialize camera. Please try restarting device.");
}
```

When the application starts on my phone it throws this RuntimeException.

**openDrive** method :

```
  public synchronized void openDriver(SurfaceHolder holder) throws IOException {
Camera theCamera = camera;
if (theCamera == null) {
  theCamera = Camera.open();
  if (theCamera == null) {
    throw new IOException();
  }
  camera = theCamera;
}
camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
if (!initialized) {
  initialized = true;
  configManager.initFromCameraParameters(theCamera);
  if (requestedFramingRectWidth > 0 && requestedFramingRectHeight > 0) {
    adjustFramingRect(requestedFramingRectWidth, requestedFramingRectHeight);
    requestedFramingRectWidth = 0;
    requestedFramingRectHeight = 0;
  }
}
configManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(theCamera);

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
reverseImage = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_REVERSE_IMAGE, false);
}
```

any thoughts how i can solve this problem ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A quick debug tip would be to compile the app for targetSdkVersion 19. Looks like between the API versions the Camera interface must have depriciated some stuff. Also if you have capability to see kernel logs via a serial terminal or via adb it would be helpful to see what the "Error: -1" means to the hardware i.e. is it really reaching the camera driver in kernel?

```
adb root
adb shell
#cat /proc/kmsg
```

Comment: i don't have access ! it says permission denied when i run `cat /proc/kmsg` ! and as i just bought the phone i don't intend to root it.. Please check my updated request !